# neo4j : How to Create the bidirectional Relationships in graph database?

Tags: neo4j

I tried to create bidirectional relationships by using this pattern (u1)-[:]-(u2) and also this one (u1)<-[:]->(u2).

but at the end result is directed to one part of the nodes from the first parenthesis to last one (u1)-[:]->(u2).

How to achieve bidirectional relationships here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Neo4j cannot store bidirectional relationships. 
No way around this, however, you can treat relationships as bidirectional when querying your graph.